# How to prove the minimality of a minimal polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

I have a problem: find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3$ over $\mathbb Q$

I can calculate the answer i.e. $x^4-10x^2+1$ but how can I prove the minimality? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A brute force route open to you is that you undoubtedly know the other roots of the quartic as well. Therefore you can list all the potential linear and quadratic factors, and conclude that none of them have rational coefficients. This would show that your quartic is irreducible. As you see from the answers, there are also other ways.

Comment: The question of the title has a trivial answer: the minimal polynomial is minimal by definition. What you are asking about is a specific annihilating polynomial, that might not be the minimal polynomial (though in the end it is).

Answer (score 9):

*Hint;* $\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3 \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$, which has degree $4$ over $\mathbb Q$. Therefore, the degree of every element is $1$, $2$, or $4$. Prove that $\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3$ does not have degree $1$ or $2$. (Use that $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$.)

Answer (score 5):

$$(a+b+c)\prod_{cyc}(a+b-c)=\sum_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-c^4).$$
For $a=\sqrt2$, $b=\sqrt3$ and $c=x$ we obtain:
$$2(6+2x^2+3x^2)-4-9-x^4=0,$$
which gives
$$x^4-10x^2+1=0.$$
Now, easy to show that $x^4-10x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

and $\sqrt2+\sqrt3\notin\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Would you mind adding some detail to your response? Where did the first line come from? What does the subscript "cyc" mean?

Comment: @Ken Duna $\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b-c)=(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)$ and $\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)=2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)-a^4-b^4-c^4$.

Comment: [Newton's polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Advanced_explanation) (a slightly more advanced version of Eisenstein's criterion) seems to imply that the quartic is irreducible ($x=y+1, p=2$) even though the usual Eisenstein does not. The lower convex envelope of the polygon of
$$(y+1)^4-10(y+1)^2+1=y^4+4y^3-4y^2-16y-8$$ is the line segment connecting the points $(0,3)$ and $(4,0)$. This has slope $-3/4$. The denominator four implies irreducibility as in that WP-link.

Comment: Right you are, @JyrkiLahtonen — it doesn’t merely seem to imply, it really does imply. Beyond that, with suitable further rational substitutions,  you can get to a genuine Eisenstein polynomial. After all, the ramification degree at $2$ is $4$.

Answer (score 4):

It is enough to exploit a bit of linear algebra. We have that $\alpha^2-2\in\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\beta^2-3\in\mathbb{Q}[\beta]$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3}$. A base of the ring $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha,\beta]/(\alpha^2-2,\beta^2-3)$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ is given by $1,\alpha,\beta,\alpha\beta$, and we may represent every polynomial $(\alpha+\beta)^n$ with respect to such a base:
$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\text{Polynomial}&1&\alpha&\beta&\alpha\beta\\ \hline (\alpha+\beta)^0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\hline (\alpha+\beta)^1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline (\alpha+\beta)^2 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\hline (\alpha+\beta)^3 & 0 & 11 & 9 & 0 \\
\hline (\alpha+\beta)^4 & 49 & 0 & 0 & 20 \\
\hline  \end{array}$$
Given five vectors in $\mathbb{Q}^4$, there always is a non-trivial linear combination of them that equals zero.
In the present case the fifth row minus ten times the third row plus the first row gives zero, hence $z^4-10z^2+1$ is a polynomial that vanishes at $\alpha+\beta$.  That is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ because the matrix
$$ M=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 5 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 11 & 9 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
is invertible, hence there isn't any non-trivial polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}_{\leq 3}[x]$ vanishing at $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Really elegant, thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = (x-1)$. Then $x = y+1$ and so your polynomial can be expressed as a polynomial in $y$, which is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion using the prime $2$, and hence your polynomial is also irreducible. Of course, the general proof of linear independence (as mentioned by *lhf*) is the way to go if you want the general result that the sum of square-roots of primes generates the whole field extension.